# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Random to int

Tags: java, type-mismatch

How can I fill this array with random int's and avoid this type mismatch error? I have tried to cast but I wasn't very successful.
Thanks

```
public static int[] generateRandom(int n) {
    Random r = new Random(1);
    r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    int[] ranArray = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ranArray[i] = r;
    }
    printArray(ranArray);
    return ranArray;
}
```

Comment: Change `ranArray[i] = r;` by `ranArray[i] = r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`. By the way, the compiler error is pretty descriptive by itself.

Comment: When the answer to a question is _"you can't <insert error message>"_, you probably shouldn't have posted the question

Comment: Thanks for downvoting...

Comment: @user2899352 People are downvoting because you obviously didn't attempt to fix this yourself.  The very first link in the google search "java Random nextInt example" would have solved this for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant assign `Random` type to int

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ranArray[i] = r;           // Type mismatch
}
```

Instead do this

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ranArray[i] = r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);;
}
```

Comment: Note that if you call `r.nextInt()` (without an argument) then the randomly generated numbers can be either positive or negative. By using `r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`, as suggested here, you can make sure you only get non-negative random numbers.

Comment: Thanks, but i am only using `r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` because the OP had this in his code.

Comment: Ha—I didn't even notice that. I thought you'd somehow gleaned that he probably only wanted positive integers, and I wanted to explain how you were achieving that. I guess the OP already knew that though.

Answer (score 0):

r is of type `Random` whereas `ranArray[i]` is integer and hence the error.